# Possible to nest a $.post within another Deferred/Promise

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I seem to having some issues nesting a Post within a Promise without running into timing issues (or I think they're timing issues...). In my scenario I need a Post to fire within a $.when() but it can't continue/return until it is complete.

I've attempted this with/without a nested $.when for the Post, but am still having no luck. I've broken down my code to only 1 section, as my $.when is much larger:

```
$.when(calcQualifier()).then(function (status) {
    $("#stuff").append(status);
    return calcTotals(); // working function, not shown
}).then(function (status) {
    $("#stuff").append("Complete");
});

function calcQualifier() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var serialized = "" //build json here (works fine)
        $.when(calcQualifier_Post(serialized)).then(function (status) {
            def.resolve("Qualifier Calculated <br/>");
            return def.promise();
        });
}

function calcQualifier_Post(serialized) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.post("/Opportunity/CalculateQualifier/", serialized, 
      function (returnJson) {
        var qualifier = returnJson.Qualifier;
        //update view with qualifier results
        return def.promise();
    });
}
```

In the above scenario, all other .then() items fire fine, but anything with a Post never seems to fire in the correct order.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the promises immediately (before resolving them). If you don't, the `.when()` doesn't get a reference to the deferred object to know when it has been resolved.

```
$.when(calcQualifier()).then(function (status) {
    $("#stuff").append(status);
    return calcTotals(); // working function, not shown
}).then(function (status) {
    $("#stuff").append("Complete");
});

function calcQualifier() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var serialized = "" //build json here (works fine)
    $.when(calcQualifier_Post(serialized)).then(function (status) {
        def.resolve("Qualifier Calculated <br/>");
    });
    return def.promise();
}

function calcQualifier_Post(serialized) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.post("/Opportunity/CalculateQualifier/", serialized, function (returnJson) {
        var qualifier = returnJson.Qualifier;
        //update view with qualifier results
        def.resolve(true);
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This was right under my nose the entire time. Not only did your comment solve my problem, but it also helped me understand the resolve, reject etc functions.